# speeding up seek pagination with complex queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an API with an underlying MySQL database.

I have some complex queries that involve multiple joins and some of these tables are huge (> 200 million rows).

I am using seek pagination by ordering my query results based off of a uid and fetching the page after the last uid.

For most queries this is very fast, however if the query returns a set where there is a big jump in uids on a page this becomes very slow.

For example if page one returns uids 1,2,3,4, and 5 its super fast but if the query returns uids 1,2,3 50000000, and 50000001 the query gets super slow (~100 sec).

Any ideas how to speed this up?

Here is one complex query, and the table structure around it with indexes:

```
>Q1 (fast if there is no jump in h.uid)
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN *
FROM h use index(ix_join) JOIN r ON r.uid = h.rID JOIN so ON so.uid = h.soID 
JOIN e ON e.uid = h.eID JOIN sa ON sa.uid = h.saID 
WHERE r.chr = '2' AND r.r1 >= 99999999 AND r.r2 <= 103000000 AND r.bin
IN (0, 2, 20, 21, 168, 169, 170, 171, 1347, 1348, 1349, 1350, 1351, 1352, 1353, 1354, 1355, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1360, 1361, 1362, 1363, 1364, 1365, 1366, 1367, 1368, 1369, 1370) 
AND h.uid > 77178 ORDER BY h.uid
LIMIT 1000

>explain Q1
id|select_type|table |type  |possible_keys             |key    |key_len|ref         |rows     |Extra                      |
--|-----------|------|------|--------------------------|-------|-------|------------|---------|---------------------------|
 1|SIMPLE     |h     |ALL   |ix_join                   |       |       |            |162690954|Using where; Using filesort|
 1|SIMPLE     |r     |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid,ix_bin_chr |PRIMARY|4      |hg38.h.rID  |        1|Using where                |
 1|SIMPLE     |so    |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid            |PRIMARY|4      |hg38.h.soID |        1|                           |
 1|SIMPLE     |e     |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid            |PRIMARY|4      |hg38.h.eID  |        1|                           |
 1|SIMPLE     |sa    |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid            |PRIMARY|4      |hg38.h.saID |        1|                           |

>Q2 (takes about 15s regardless of jumps in h.uid)
SELECT *
FROM h use index(ix_join) JOIN r ON r.uid = h.rID JOIN so ON so.uid = h.soID 
JOIN e ON e.uid = h.eID JOIN sa ON sa.uid = h.saID 
WHERE r.chr = '2' AND r.r1 >= 99999999 AND r.r2 <= 103000000 AND r.bin
IN (0, 2, 20, 21, 168, 169, 170, 171, 1347, 1348, 1349, 1350, 1351, 1352, 1353, 1354, 1355, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1360, 1361, 1362, 1363, 1364, 1365, 1366, 1367, 1368, 1369, 1370) 
AND h.uid > 77178 ORDER BY h.uid
LIMIT 1000

>explain Q2
id|select_type|table |type  |possible_keys             |key         |key_len|ref         |rows  |Extra                                                              |
--|-----------|------|------|--------------------------|------------|-------|------------|------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 1|SIMPLE     |r     |range |PRIMARY,ix_uid,ix_bin_chr |ix_bin_chr  |19     |            |494112|Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|
 1|SIMPLE     |h     |ref   |ix_join                   |ix_join     |4      |hg38.r.uid  |     1|Using index condition                                              |
 1|SIMPLE     |so    |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid            |PRIMARY     |4      |hg38.h.soID |     1|                                                                   |
 1|SIMPLE     |e     |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid            |PRIMARY     |4      |hg38.h.eID  |     1|                                                                   |
 1|SIMPLE     |sa    |eq_ref|PRIMARY,ix_uid            |PRIMARY     |4      |hg38.h.saID |     1|                                                                   |

>desc h
Field       |Type            |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
------------|----------------|----|---|-------|--------------|
uid         |int(10) unsigned|NO  |PRI|       |auto_increment|
type        |varchar(25)     |NO  |   |       |              |
score       |float           |YES |   |       |              |
peak        |int(11)         |YES |   |       |              |
rID         |int(10) unsigned|NO  |MUL|       |              |
saID        |int(10) unsigned|NO  |MUL|       |              |
eID         |int(10) unsigned|NO  |MUL|       |              |
soID        |int(10) unsigned|NO  |MUL|       |              |

Table |Non_unique|Key_name    |Seq_in_index|Column_name |Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|
------|----------|------------|------------|------------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|
h     |         0|PRIMARY     |           1|uid         |A        |  162690954|        |      |    |BTREE     |
h     |         1|ix_join     |           1|rID         |A        |  162690954|        |      |    |BTREE     |
h     |         1|ix_join     |           2|saID        |A        |  162690954|        |      |    |BTREE     |
h     |         1|ix_join     |           3|eID         |A        |  162690954|        |      |    |BTREE     |
h     |         1|ix_join     |           4|so ID       |A        |  162690954|        |      |    |BTREE     |

>desc r
Field|Type                |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
-----|--------------------|----|---|-------|--------------|
uid  |int(10) unsigned    |NO  |PRI|       |auto_increment|
bin  |smallint(5) unsigned|NO  |MUL|       |              |
chr  |varchar(5)          |NO  |MUL|       |              |
r1   |int(10) unsigned    |NO  |   |       |              |
r2   |int(10) unsigned    |NO  |   |       |              |

Table  |Non_unique|Key_name    |Seq_in_index|Column_name|Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|
-------|----------|------------|------------|-----------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|
r      |         0|PRIMARY     |           1|uid        |A        |  217539807|        |      |    |BTREE     ||
r      |         1|ix_uid      |           1|uid        |A        |  217539807|        |      |    |BTREE     |
r      |         1|ix_bin_chr  |           1|bin        |A        |         18|        |      |    |BTREE     |
r      |         1|ix_bin_chr  |           2|chr        |A        |     103491|        |      |    |BTREE     |

>desc sa 
Field    |Type                |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
---------|--------------------|----|---|-------|--------------|
uid      |int(10) unsigned    |NO  |PRI|       |auto_increment|
name     |varchar(250)        |NO  |MUL|       |              |

Table  |Non_unique|Key_name                     |Seq_in_index|Column_name|Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|
-------|----------|-----------------------------|------------|-----------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|
sa     |         0|PRIMARY                      |           1|uid        |A        |        574|        |      |    |BTREE     |
sa     |         1|ix_name                      |           1|name       |A        |        574|        |      |    |BTREE     |

>desc so
Field              |Type            |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
-------------------|----------------|----|---|-------|--------------|
uid                |int(10) unsigned|NO  |PRI|       |auto_increment|
name               |varchar(250)    |NO  |MUL|       |              |
so_metadata        |varchar(250)    |YES |   |       |              |
metadata_descriptor|varchar(250)    |YES |   |       |              |
url                |varchar(250)    |YES |   |       |              |
insert_date        |datetime        |NO  |   |       |              |

Table  |Non_unique|Key_name|Seq_in_index|Column_name        |Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|
-------|----------|--------|------------|-------------------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|
so     |         0|PRIMARY |           1|uid                |A        |       2161|        |      |    |BTREE     |
so     |         1|ix_name |           1|name               |A        |         24|        |      |    |BTREE     |

>desc e

Field              |Type            |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
-------------------|----------------|----|---|-------|--------------|
uid                |int(10) unsigned|NO  |PRI|       |auto_increment|
name               |varchar(250)    |NO  |MUL|       |              |
e_metadata         |varchar(250)    |YES |   |       |              |
metadata_descriptor|varchar(250)    |YES |   |       |              |

Table      |Non_unique|Key_name|Seq_in_index|Column_name        |Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|
-----------|----------|--------|------------|-------------------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|
e          |         0|PRIMARY |           1|uid                |A        |          6|        |      |    |BTREE     |
e          |         1|ix_name |           1|name               |A        |          6|        |      |    |BTREE     |
```

Comment: How is your table indexed?

Comment: I have an index on the primary key (uid) of the main table as well as a compound index on all the foreign keys on that table. All the tables that are joint have primary key indexes and indexes on any columns that are used in the select statements.

Comment: @TamarAv-Shalom can you share the structure of the relevant tables and queries involved?

Comment: @StevenMoseley I have added one query and the indexes of the connecting tables.

Comment: @tim i have added how the tables are indexed.